# How to merge two DataFrames by complicated condition?

Tags: python, pandas

Python 3.9.5

The first big DataFrame contains points and the second big DataFrame contains square areas. Square areas are defined by four straight lines, that are parallel to the coordinate axes and are completely defined by a set of constraints: y_min, y_max, x_min, x_max. For example:

```
points = pd.DataFrame({'y':[0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 1.5], 'x':[0.5, 1.5, 1.5, 0.5]})
points
          y          x
0       0.5        0.5
1       0.5        1.5
2       1.5        1.5
3       1.5        0.5

square_areas = pd.DataFrame({'y_min':[0,1], 'y_max':[1,2], 'x_min':[0,1], 'x_max':[1,2]})
square_areas
     y_min    y_max     x_min     x_max
0        0        1         0         1
1        1        2         1         2
```

How to get all points, that don't belong to square areas without sequential enumeration of areas in a cycle?

Needed Output:

```py
         y          x
0      0.5        1.5
1      1.5        0.5
```

Comment: Will you please make a sample dataframe that you want to get as output?

Comment: I have corrected the post.

Comment: Will you please explain a bit the logic here? I think it's probably not very complex but I'm having a bit of trouble getting a hold of it right now.

Comment: Square areas are defined by four straight lines, that are parallel to the coordinate axes and are completely defined by a set of constraints: y_min, y_max, x_min, x_max. All points falling within these areas must be excluded. In the example, we have two areas where 1 point falls for each, so there should be only two points left.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do this with a 'merge', but you can iterate over the square_areas dataframe and evaluate the conditions of the point dataframe.

I'm assuming you'll have more than two test cases, so this iterative approach should work. Each iteration only looks at points that have not been evaluated by a prior square_areas row.

```
points = pd.DataFrame({'y':[0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 1.5], 'x':[0.5, 1.5, 1.5, 0.5]})
print(points)
# assume everything is outside until it evaluates inside
points['outside'] = 'Y'

square_areas = pd.DataFrame({'y_min':[0,1], 'y_max':[1,2], 'x_min':[0,1], 'x_max':[1,2]})
print(square_areas)

for i in range(square_areas.shape[0]):
    ymin = square_areas.iloc[i]['y_min']
    ymax = square_areas.iloc[i]['y_max']
    xmin = square_areas.iloc[i]['x_min']
    xmax = square_areas.iloc[i]['x_max']

    points.loc[points['outside'] == 'Y', 'outside'] = np.where(points[points['outside'] == 'Y']['x'].between(xmin, xmax) & points[points['outside'] == 'Y']['y'].between(ymin, ymax), 'N', points[points['outside'] == 'Y']['outside'])
    
points.loc[points['outside'] == 'Y']
```

Output

```
        y       x outside
1 0.50000 1.50000       Y
3 1.50000 0.50000       Y
```

Comment: Thank you! But I have a big DataFrame with square areas, so I get a very large loop, at each iteration of which a rather resource-intensive operation of searching points in the current area is performed. Under such conditions, the issue of performance comes first.